# Error creating a Node Module with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to separate my functions into their own file to keep the code clean, and upon moving this function and it's helper function I can't compile the program anymore. I get the error

```
const msToTime = (duration: number): string => {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Heres the code:

```
const msToTime = (duration: number): string => {
    var minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
        hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    return hours == 0 ? `${minutes} minute(s)` : `${hours} hours and ${minutes} minute(s)`;
}

export async function alertStudent(client: any, studentID: string, assignments: Array<any>) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like your file is being parsed as JavaScript instead of TypeScript; could you share some more information on the project structure/config?

Comment: That skipped my mind, turns out I did 
require("file.ts") instead of .js